Django channels giving error with "async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})"
I'm trying the django channels tutorial. im at the part where we are making sure that the channel layer can communicate with redis. i've already run the following commands-
$ docker run --rm -p 6379:6379 redis:7
$ python3 -m pip install channels_redis

# mysite/settings.py
# Channels
ASGI_APPLICATION = "mysite.asgi.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}

im supposed to run this->
$ python3 manage.py shell

>>>import channels.layers

>>>channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()

>>>from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

>>>async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})

>>>async_to_sync(channel_layer.receive)('test_channel')
{'type': 'hello'}`

but i keep getting error that it cannot connect with redis at line ">>>async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})"
ive run the tutorial commands but it keeps on showing error that it cannot connect to redis. there are so many lines of error. i asked gpt and it told that it cannot connect to redis
